# Did any Western consulates remain open or re-open after WWII in the same buildings in which they had resided in Wuhan, Hebei, China?

Tags: world-war-two, china, building, diplomatic-history, foreign-policy

The recent CNN article [From one-time Chinese capital to coronavirus epicenter, Wuhan has a long history that the West had forgotten](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/02/22/asia/wuhan-history-hnk-intl/index.html)

> Two generations ago, this city of 11 million people, on the junction of the Yangtze and Han Rivers, 600 miles upstream, in central China, was known through the West as a major industrial city.
>
> **It was somewhere many European powers had a consulate**, a place where major Western and Japanese trading firms, and international textile and engineering companies, had factories and sales offices.
>
> It was a regular overseas posting for customs officers, steamboat captains, traders and consuls. Wuhan was also a cradle of China's revolution in 1911. A quarter of a century later, it stood defiantly as the beleaguered wartime capital of nationalist China.

and later

> The new arrivals clustered in Hankou creating a tree-lined, two-mile long Bund, which largely remains today, building their warehouses, docks and offices as well as a race track, clubs and public gardens all adjacent to the Hankou waterfront.
>
> The British Concession was adjacent to concessions run by the Germans, the French, the Japanese, a rather disputed Belgian concession, and the Russians, who had been active in Wuhan trading tea from Siberia since the 12th century. **All these nations, including the Americans, had consulates.**

and later

> While Wuhan became a cosmopolitan place, it was always essentially a business town -- it never developed the nightlife or the movie industry, publishing houses, and art galleries that clustered in Shanghai's more Bohemian quarters; it wasn't quite the scholarly center that was Beijing. **The foreigners were present, and their soldiers guarded the consulates, but the city retained a more dominant Chinese feel.**

I'm assuming that at least some of these consulates were closed as a result of World War II:

> After the chaos and destruction of the Second World War, the Communist Revolution brought the Bamboo Curtain firmly down. International trade stopped, the foreign business community left, and the Western world largely forgot about Wuhan.

---

**Question:** Did any Western consulates remain open during or re-open within the decade after WWII in the same buildings in which they had resided in Wuhan city, Hebei province, China?

Comment: somewhat related: [Why did Japan take so long to attack Wuhan?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/26627/33008)

Comment: The timeline of your question seems contradictory. In which periods (1 or 2 decades only please) are you referring to with "*I'm assuming that at least some of these consulates were closed during or after WWII*" and "*Did any Western consulates remain open or re-open ... in which they had resided in Wuhan ...*"?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Thanks. I've adjusted the wording; "as a result of World War II" and near the end "remain open during or re-open within within the decade after WWII" Do these  sufficiently address your concern?

Comment: "tea from Siberia"???

Comment: @AaronBrick ya that might be a stand-alone question by itself, then again it might be just an editorial slip-up. Maybe  the Chinese traded tea for something else?